# Can I provide absolute path for .dll at compile time in windows?

Tags: dll, window, rpath

I created one .dll(Dynamic link library). Using this library I want create executable file.

But I want to provide absolute path for .dll to link with .exe. So when I execute .exe it links with .dll.

I don't want to set PATH(environment variable), don't want to put .dll into system directory or into same directory within executable.
I know that it is possible into linux using -rpath option.

I am new to windows. I try to find rpath equal option in window, but I failed.